# What is the difference between expressions and statements in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

In Erlang, what is the difference between Expressions and Statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Erlang, everything has a value.

So, the difference is that Erlang has expressions but does not have statements.

That explains Erlang's (arguably) wacky "if" expression.

Since it, and everything else, must evaluate to some kind of value, people often end them with a "true -> ok" clause to ensure the if doesn't crash at runtime.

Comment: Also expressions don't have default values so in function, case and if you need to have clauses which cover every case otherwise you get errors. This was intentional.